# Columns variables as input in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and i have a problem. I want to make columns variables as input selection. How i cant do this, for example i have data different data sets like that, district tehsil parameters are same but values column is different. in data table when i select input data set then it displays total table, but i want to made another input when i select some specific district then it only shows tehsil and values of this district other wise all. I have attached the data set example pic
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyuef.png)

```
dataset<-c(Biometric_Attendance,CFM_Parchi,Cleanliness,Consultant_Posting,Medicine_Dispensation,OverAll_Summary)library(shiny)library(rgdal)library(maptools)shinyApp(shinyUI(
fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,selectInput("dataset","Facility Wise", choices =c("OverAll_Summary","Biometric_Attendance", "CFM_Parchi", "Cleanliness","Consultant_Posting")),selectInput("Dist",
        #  "District",
         # c("All",
           # unique(as.character(dataset$DISTRICT)))),downloadButton('downloadData', 'DownloadFacilitySummary')),mainPanel(tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Facility Wise Summary", dataTableOutput("table1"))
```

server side code here

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
datasetInput1 <- reactive({
  switch(input$dataset,
         "Biometric_Attendance" = Biometric_Attendance,
         "CFM_Parchi" = CFM_Parchi,
         "Cleanliness" = Cleanliness,
         "Consultant_Posting" = Consultant_Posting ,
        "OverAll_Summary"=OverAll_Summary)
}) output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
  data <- dataset
  if (input$Dist != "All") {
    data <- data[data$DISTRICT == input$Dist,]
  }
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() { 
    paste(input$dataset, '.csv', sep='') 
  },
  content = function(file) {
    write.csv(datasetInput1(), file)
  }
)
})
```

Comment: Can you make a small, reproducible example of the Shiny program you designed?

Comment: Please share your code if you already tried anything, otherwise have a look at http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/ to get started.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik  i have updated code please